# Is it true that $\forall x\in \mathbb Z: (-x-1,x)\in R^2$ if $(x,y)\in R \iff x^2+x = y^2+y$?

Tags: proof-verification, relations

> Given that $(x,y)\in R$ (where $R$ is a relation) $\iff x^2+x=y^2+y$ is it true that for all $x\in \mathbb Z: (-x-1,x)\in R^2$?

Certainly $R$ contains the identity relation. In addition:
$$
x^2+x = y^2 + y \implies x+y=-1, x-y \neq 0
$$
so $R=I_{\mathbb Z} \cup \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&1&-2&2&-3\dots\\-1&0&-2&1&-3&2 \dots\end{pmatrix}$

which essentially makes $R$ an equivalence relation.

Then $R^2=R$ so I guess the statement is false.

Comment: Any relation $S$ with $(x, y)\in S\iff f(x) = f(y)$ for some function $f$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: @ArnaudD. $R^2$ equals the identity relation of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If $R^2$ is the identity relation, then clearly it's _not_ true that $(-x-1,x)\in R^2$ for all $x$, since it's not true that $(1, -1-1) = (1, -2)$ is an element of the identity relation. Are you certain you don't mean "for all $x\in \mathbb Z: (-x-1,x)\in R$"?

Comment: I meant : what does $R^2$ denote? How is it defined? If it's supposed to be the composition of the relation $R$ with itself, then it's false : any equivalence relation composed with itself is itself again (in fact this is even true for preorders).

Comment: @ArnaudD. yes it's denoted as composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exercise.  Show R = $R^2.$
Thus your problem becomes showing
(-x-1,x) in R for all x in Z.

Does $(-x-1)^2 + (-x-1) = x^2 + x?

Comment: yes it holds true.